# Why rejection of a true null hypothesis is called type I error?

Tags: confusion-matrix, hypothesis-testing

I’m comparing two confusion matrices:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix#Table_of_confusion
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors

The 2nd is rotated, the Decision is on Y-axis. But I assume both reflect the same concept.

I have two options to render the word “Reject”.

(1) When we look at Null hypothesis matrix, the Reject of a “True Null hypothesis” means a decision which doesn’t reflect reality (convicting an innocent), and this is indeed FP (type I).

(2) Following Confusion_matrix wiki, I interpret Reject as False. Therefore, making a False decision (H0 is false) over Actual True (H0 is true) brings me to claim this is FN (type II).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352326/why-the-names-type-1-2-error

Comment: Thank you. Very close but not. I see a contradiction in these two confusion matrices (CM). The FN and FP are swapped. I see two variations of CM, one for classification and another for hypothesis testing.
Rejecting something which is true, called FN.
From wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives
"FN is a test result which wrongly indicates that a condition does not hold"
condition = H0
And therefore, Rejecting true H0 should be called FN, type II error.

Answer (score 1):

In order to co-exist these two confusion matrices above we need to understand what statisticians call True/False and Positive/Negative. Let’s apply a linear transformation  on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors) matrix and replace “Null Hypothesis is True” by “Alternative is False”.

|  | (H0 is False) Alternative is True | (H0 is True) Alternative is False |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Reject H0 = Accept Alternative (Positive) | TP | FP (Type I error) |
| Don’t Reject H0 = Reject Alternative (Negative) | FN (Type II error) | TN |